# Xcode !Go from home view with button to a specific view in tab bar controller

Tags: objective-c, xcode, tabbar

I have a view with 3 buttons and a tabbar controller that contains 3 views. I am using the storyboard. I want go from my view to a specific view from the tabbar controller.for example i want to push the second button in the home view and i want to go directly to the second tab of my tab bar controller.

Comment: Could you please re-word your question? It is kinda hard to determine what exactly are you trying to achieve.

Comment: i have a single view with three buttons and a tab bar controller with three tabs.i want to link the three buttons in the "home" view with the respective view in tab bar controller. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can programmatically change tabs by inserting the following into you void/IBAction.

```
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how do i define tabbarcontroller?? can you write me an example with .h and .m file??

Comment: @RaffaeleDiFlorio this is done automatically using a tabbarcontroller.

Comment: Sorry but i'm a beginner. I inserted the code you provided in the action of my button: -(IBaction) goView2 { [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
} but it doesn't work :(